# How to convert from snake_case to CamelCase (aka PascalCase) using TCL?

Tags: tcl

Ideally I'm looking for a one-liner `regsub` or similar to convert a string variable `$name` from snake_case to another string variable `$class_name` using CamelCase.

Example:

```
"simple" -> "Simple"
"not_so_simple" -> "NotSoSimple"
```

I'm currently searching for `_`, removing it then replacing the following letter with `toupper`, but I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Terminological note: `thisIsCamelCase`; meanwhile, `ThisIsCalledTitleCase`.

Comment: @Amadan Not according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), which conflates the two (as PascalCase and dromedaryCase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you insist on using `regsub`, so I'm just ignoring that part. Using `lmap` you can do it using a one-line like this:

```
join [lmap s [split $str _] {string totitle $s}] ""
```

This works in Tcl 8.6 and later. For earlier versions, a simple script-only implementation of `lmap` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm currently searching for _, removing it then replacing the
>   following letter with toupper, but I'm hoping to find a more elegant
>   solution.

How much control do you have of the input? Is the input guaranteed to have a certain form?

If it is under your control, regular expressions are not needed, you might take a detour via a Tcl list using [`split`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm) and then run the transform using [`string totitle`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M45). Watch:

```
% set name "not_so_simple"
% join [lmap el [split $name _] {string totitle $el}] ""
NotSoSimple
```

This will work in Tcl starting with 8.6 upwards. Below, you would have to use an in-place loop to replace `lmap`.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Tcl 8.7 (currently in alphas/development), it's not too difficult with a command replacement:

```
regsub -all -command {(?:^|\W|_)[a-z]} $string {apply {match {
    string toupper [string trimleft $match "_"]
}}} string
```

(That works with your two use cases.)

With earlier releases, it's quite a bit messier:

```
# NB: do replacements from back to front so indices remaining to be replaced are still valid
foreach range [lreverse [regexp -all -inline -indices {(?:^|\W|_)[a-z]} $string]] {
    set match [string range $string {*}$range]
    set replacement [string toupper [string trimleft $match "_"]]
    set string [string replace $string {*}$range $replacement]
}
```

You can also do trickery with `regsub` and `subst`, but I find that much harder to write (I have to test much more thoroughly!). That's why there's a `-command` option to `regsub` in 8.7…

Comment: I didn't do the first version as a one-liner because I don't like to make lines very long; combining is left as an exercise. Also note that I'm using the same RE in both cases.

Comment: Tcl 8.6, unfortunately, but your `foreach` helped simplify mine (I was going from front to back with `while`, and was cutting strings up rather than using replace). Thanks!